# How can I change my gradle to @public APIs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I got following message when I change from Maven to Gradle.
How can I change to using public apis only?

> /*
>
> - This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
> - 
> - This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
>   */

`build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
    }
}

dependencies {
    
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
description = ""
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `build.gradle` file look like? It's hard to tell which incubating API you use, without seeing your build script.

Comment: update @Endzeit

Comment: The build script you've posted does not contain any incubating APIs as of Gradle `v7.3`.

Comment: Where do you see the statement about incubating APIs? In the shell when executing Gradle? Or written into a build file?